# Visa requirements to Croatia for Russian citizens

Tags: visas, croatia, russian-language

I am going to a scientific conference in Croatia. I saw on the website that if I am a Russian citizen but go to Croatia for educational, scientific or cultural issues I still require a visa but it will be free. Is this information valid?

Comment: Which website did you see this on?

Comment: See the [official website](http://ru.mfa.hr/ru/) for [visas](http://ru.mfa.hr/ru/konzularne-informacije/vizy/) and [visa fees](http://ru.mfa.hr/ru/konzularne-informacije/vizy/vizovye-posliny/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, VFS Global handles the visa to Croatia in Russia. The only thing is that you cannot stay there for more than 90 days. The website clearly states:

> Visa Fees waived categories
>
> > Members of the immediate family of a Croatian, EU and EEA citizens (spouse and children)
>
> If you plan to go to Croatia to some visit for a period not to exceed 90 days and your country is not on the visa-free list, you need a other visa (Visa C).